# Magento 2: How to get type columns of table in sql?

Tags: magento2

I want get type columns of table in sql ?

---

Comment: you mean column type ???

Answer (score 1):

```
*Try To run Following code to get column datatype by Magento way.*

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('core_config_data');

$sql = "DESCRIBE $tableName";
$connection->query($sql);

**NOTE: Don't use direct ObjectManager try to use di.**
```

Comment: it does not working. i want get type of catalog_product_entity table.

Comment: please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check `type of column` like `varchar(255)`, `int(11)` etc.

You can use:

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

**for example:**

```
 DESCRIBE core_config_data;
```

it will show :

[image]

Hope above will help!

Comment: thank your answer but i want get data_type of table for add columns!